# NameError, Variable not displaying stored text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a bit of code for a class assignment, and for the life of me I can't get a variable to display the text I'm storing in it:

```
if (salesavg < 5000):
    rank = "SAD SALESMEN"
    if (salesavg >= 5000 or salesavg <= 8000):
        rank = "LOW SALESMAN"
        if (salesavg >= 8001 or salesavg <= 9000):
            rank = "MID SALESMAN"
            if (salesavg >= 9001 or salesavg <= 10000):
                rank = "EXCELLENT SALESMAN"
                if (salesavg > 10000):
                   rank = "TOP SALESMAN"
```

And where it's supposed to display:

```
print("RANKING: " ,rank)
```

Not in a massive hurry, but I am baffled as to why it's not working, I've used similar methods in other sections of this program and they work fine!

Answered: Thank you! Changing it them to elif and from or to and fixed the issue I was having (also reversing the order). Works perfectly now.

Comment: For all _x_, x>=5000 **or** x<=8000.  Use Python's `5000 <= salesavg <= 8000` syntax (but not here because of the restructuring others have suggested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use elif, not just if. What is happening is that the code checks if salesavg < 5000 and if it that is not true, it just hops past all the other if statements because those can only trigger if the first one triggers. Then the variable rank hasn't been declared because the if statements were never triggered.

Here is what I would do:

```
if (salesavg > 10000):
    rank = "TOP SALESMAN"
elif (salesavg >= 9001 or salesavg <= 10000):
    rank = "EXCELLENT SALESMAN"   
elif (salesavg >= 8001 or salesavg <= 9000):
    rank = "MID SALESMAN"
elif (salesavg >= 5000 or salesavg <= 8000):
    rank = "LOW SALESMAN"
elif (salesavg < 5000):
    rank = "SAD SALESMEN"
```

Also notice that I changed the order so that it looks for the highest first. This is because the Top salesman would otherwise have just triggered any of the other, smaller, levels first. Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you messed up the formatting but I think you messed up your logic:
All of you if loops are nested meaning that

```
if (salesavg >= 5000 or salesavg <= 8000):
```

will only run if salesavg < 5000

which is illogical, so to fix this do:

```
if salesavg < 5000: rank = "SAD SALESMEN"
elif salesavg <= 8000: rank = "LOW SALESMAN"
elif salesavg <= 9000: rank = "MID SALESMAN"
elif salesavg <= 10000: rank = "EXCELLENT SALESMAN"
elif salesavg > 10000): rank = "TOP SALESMAN"
# this last one could just be else: rank = "TOP SALESMAN"
```

**EDIT** optimized it

Answer (score 0):

In Python, indentations are used to determine how statements are structured.

In your code, inside

```
if (salesavg < 5000):
```

The nested condition

```
    if (salesavg >= 5000 and salesavg <= 8000):
```

would NEVER be true. The same for the rest of them.

It should be something like:

```
if (salesavg < 5000): 
    rank = "SAD SALESMEN"
elif (salesavg >= 5000 and salesavg <= 8000):
    rank = "LOW SALESMAN"
//...
```

BTW, all the `or` in your code should be `and`, as I fixed in the example.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason you get no value is because you try with a salesavg of greater than 5000.

The indentation makes all of the code conditional on the first test, and the rest of the code only runs if that test passes, so the currently code only sets at all if less than 5000.

Apart from the indentation, this code could be much cleaner, and currently uses `or` in place of `and`, so any value less than the upper limit will pass every test.  There is a better method of checking values between limits in python.

```
if salesavg < 5000:
    rank = "SAD SALESMEN"
elif  5000 < salesavg <= 8000:
    rank = "LOW SALESMAN"
elif 8000 <  salesavg <= 9000:
    rank = "MID SALESMAN"
elif 9000 < salesavg <= 10000:
    rank = "EXCELLENT SALESMAN"
else: #if (salesavg > 10000):
    rank = "TOP SALESMAN"
```

This might be clearer.  Of course using else, it could also be written without testing both limits each time.

```
if salesavg < 5000:
    rank = "SAD SALESMEN"
elif salesavg <= 8000:
    rank = "LOW SALESMAN"
elif salesavg <= 9000:
    rank = "MID SALESMAN"
elif salesavg <= 10000:
    rank = "EXCELLENT SALESMAN"
else: #if (salesavg > 10000):
    rank = "TOP SALESMAN"
```